# Using spark with s3 fails on EMR, despite hadoop access working

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am trying to access a `s3://` path with

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://<path>")
```

And I get this error

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.parquet. :
>   java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3

However, running the following line

```
hadoop fs -ls <path>
```

Does work...

So I guess this might be a configuration issue between `hadoop` and `spark`

How can this be solved ?

### EDIT

After reading the suggested answer, I've tried adding the jars hard coded to the spark config, with no success

```
spark = SparkSession\
.builder.master("spark://" + master + ":7077")\
.appName("myname")\
.config("spark.jars", "/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/aws-java-sdk-1.11.221.jar,/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/hadoop-aws.jar")\
.config("spark.jars.packages", "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2")\
.getOrCreate()
```

**No success**

Comment: Looks like "s3://" is deprecated,  can you please try "s3a://" or "s3n://"

Comment: same behavior for `s3n` and `s3a`

Comment: Is this Spark on  EMR  or your custom installation on ec2/emr ? Spark on EMR should have no problem accessing S3:// prefix by default unless you messed up classpath's or deleted jars etc.  In fact it will invoke EMRFS file system for s3:// or s3n:// prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop aws dependency is missing in your project.  Please add hadoop-aws in your build.

Comment: It's a pyspark application, there's no build. How can I add this dependency when using an interactive shell ?

Comment: Please use as follows pyspark --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2.  The other way is that add the  "spark.jars.packages"  property in spark-defaults.conf file.    spark.jars.packages   com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2